# Is it acceptable to store user specific data in C# Runtime MemoryCache?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, caching

In my asp.net MVC app, each page contains a lot of data that changes very rarely, but is still user specific and should never be shared among other users.

I couldn't find a server side solution that handled a cache per-user, so my idea is to just use the 'standard' memorycache and use the user-ID as part of the key.

Is this acceptable? **Am I missing some security risks?**

Thanks

**EDIT: (added details)**

It is data that is originally stored in the database, for example, I have a custom-made dropdown list (which is retrieved using AJAX and returns a jsonresult) for product-categories. I want to be able to manually clear the cache, in case the user adds a category via settings and I need the retrieve a 'new' category list. To my knowledge I cannot manually clear the cache with **OutputCache**. I also have a scenario where I want to refresh certain cache item every minute (for some updates on the user's screen).

Comment: Are you willing to lose data?

Comment: Have you tried the OutputCache? You can implement the VarByCustom property

Comment: It is data that is originally stored in the database, for example, I have a custom-made dropdown list in a way (which is retrieved using AJAX) for product-categories. I want to be able to manually clear the cache, in case the user adds a category via settings and I need the retrieve a 'new' category list. To my knowledge I cannot manually clear the cache with OutputCache.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your action with OutputCache and for consistency make sure the action is for authorized access only.

```
[Authorized, OutputCache(VaryByCustom = "USER")]
public ActionResult SlowAction() { }
```

Then in Global.asax.cs override the 'VaryByCustom' handler

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    switch (custom)
    {
        case "USER":
            return context.User.Identity.Name;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will take a look at it if I can use the outputcache for some other purposes, but I dont think Output cache meets the full requirements regarding manual clearing etc, I updated my question above.